# How to check if a file is already being used (open) using perl. If so,forcefully close it using perl

Tags: perl

I am in a situation where I need to check if a file, say Test.xls is already opened. If the file is opened, I want my perl to forcefully close it with/without saving changes.

If not opened, my perl will create a new file and carry on with its execution.

Any inputs to it ?

Comment: If you mean "check if `Text.xls` is opened by Excel", you might be able to use OLE to ask Excel what files it has open, and to close `Test.xls` if that's one of the files.

Comment: Another option would be to try to simply open the file for writing. Most Windows applications obtain a lock on the files they open which would cause that to return an error if it's open. That won't help you close it, though.

Comment: In general, OS don't tend to list the resources processes have obtained, and they don't tend to let you invalidate the resources of other processes. That said, SysInternal's [`ProcessExplorer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) (which has been bought by MS) is capable of doing this for file handles, so there is a way. It will surely involve making low-level system calls, which you can do using Win32::API

Answer (score -2):

You can be creative!

For the functionally you can realize on two ways.

The popular first: a flat textfile, where the state of opened file(s) is notified.

Second is the same, but just as array in RAM. It's faster, while direct acessable state improves your realtime experience. If system reboots no file is opened and will not fail from popular way. There will left the flatfile after reboot, which is on last state.

Maybe you're looking for a combinition both ways, its your choice!

So you're autonom from operating system.